# Can TFS or Visual Studio remind me about issues that have to be marked as completed before a check in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, checkin

I'm actually working on a tool that need some configuration before it can be used. To save some time a hard coded some values into the text boxes of the configuration tab, so I don't have to renter them every time I do some testing or debugging.

As we're using TFS to manage our solutions I'm wondering if there is a way to mark those hard coded elements in some way so that TFS or Visual Studio 2008 will remind me to remove/replace them before I do a check in.

**UPDATE:**

The todo comments won't be a real solution as we're already using it to mark code segments which have to be reworked. We use it as a reminder for longterm tasks. And we have plenty of them so this might become a little bit unclear.

Comment: Maybe consider editing your question to include the fact that todo comments won't work for your situation. Just an idea...

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

1. [write a custom checkin policy](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=159)
2. use the existing FxCop checkin policy and [write a custom rule](http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2009/03/17/writing-custom-rules-for-tfs-2008-code-analysis-check-in-policy.aspx) (if you're marking TODOs with something that gets actually compiled, like an Attribute)
3. ditto, but via the [StyleCop checkin policy](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2009/07/updated-stylecop-checkin-policy-v121.html) (if your TODOs are source comments)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the perfect solution, but Visual Studio let's you add [TODO comments](http://dotnetperls.com/todo-comments-visual-studio) that may work well enough for you.

Comment: The todo comments won't be a real solution as we're already using it to mark code segments which have to be reworked. We use it as a reminder for longterm tasks. And we have plenty of them so this might become a little bit unclear.

Comment: You can use a different tag than TODO. If you go to Options -> Environment -> Task List you can add new tags. One could be Pre-Build.

Comment: @Ryan- that's a good suggestion. @Flo- I tend to use the ObsoleteAttribute a lot when reworking code- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could write a unit test that fails when the hardcoded stuff is found. Obviously, you won't get a reminder before checking in but you do get a build failure afterwards.